# How to reference a variable in another file without importing it?

Tags: python

If I remember correctly, it's not good coding practice for two files to import each other.

I have file A importing file B.

File B needs to perform an operation using a variable in file A.

The variable in file A can change, and when B performs its operation it needs to use the up-to-date variable in A.

What is the best way to do this?

Edit: I want to access the variable directly - not via a third party

Comment: 1) Don't have circular dependencies. 2) Pass values into functions as parameters, so you don't need to depend on specific variables in specific files.

Comment: But when I change a variable I don't want to have to pass it to all of the places where it's used - I would rather that the places reference it.

Comment: I'd say "Don't do that." There seems to be some flaw in your design in the first place.

Comment: Probably. I've thought of moving file B into a class in file A so that it can just reference a global, but I wanted to separate the code into different files.

Comment: Would storing the variables with their values as a json be useful?

Comment: Do you mean a separate json file? Maybe, although that's not really the solution I'm looking for

Comment: You could read the line from a file in both scripts. For example, have a third file called "variable.txt" and have one line represent one variable. Then you could change the variable in variable.txt and both scripts would use the new variable. Plus, it would get rid of your circular dependencies.

Comment: I can see this working with strings or ints, but what about for objects?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Python [shelve](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/shelve.html) module to store the variable from A, and then read the shelve db file from B on start. The documentation has good examples how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can evaluate the contents of a Python file using [execfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval).

e.g. Say this is the contents `vars.py`:

```
git_branch = 'feature/awesome'
```

Then `script.py` could do:

```
execfile('./vars.py')
print git_branch
```

Of course this has just been evaluated in the global scope, which could be a bit dangerous, so a safer option would be to pass in a dict to store the globals evaluated in `vars.py`:

```
vars = {}
execfile('./vars.py',vars)
print vars['git_branch']
```

Comment: Evaluating the entire file looks pretty costly for only trying to reference one variable

Comment: If the file is small enough it won't make a significant difference in speed. If the file was HUGE then yes I agree another solution would be more optimal.

Comment: Presumably the value in the *source code* won't be updated, only the runtime value. So evaling the file is not only overcomplicated, but nonsense.